# Silverlight 4 Prompting for Runtime when already installed

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Any Silverlight Devs seeing FireFox and Chrome prompt to install SL Runtime, but IE8 is fine? I'm using the Silverlight 4 Developer runtime.

Comment: What's your code for instantiating your Silverlight app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this happen when there is a problem in the aspx page.

It happened to me exactly as you described when one of my initParameters did not have a value set.

In the code sample below, note the parameter called "initParms". It has value="dummy". If you were to remove that, the same error that you describe occurs.

```
    <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="500" height="74">
        <%-- <param name="source" value="ClientBin/<app>.xap" />--%>
        <%
            string orgSourceValue = @"ClientBin/<app>.xap";
            string param;
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                param = "<param name=\"source\" value=\"" + orgSourceValue + "\" />";
            else
            {
                string xappath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"") + @"\" + orgSourceValue;
                DateTime xapCreationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(xappath);
                param = "<param name=\"source\" value=\"" + orgSourceValue + "?ignore="
                + xapCreationDate.ToString() + "\" />";
            }
            Response.Write(param);
        %>
        <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="windowless" value="true" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="enablehtmlaccess" value="true" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
        <param name="uiculture" value="<%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture %>" />
        <param name="culture" value="<%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture %>" />
        <%-- <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />--%>
        <!-- add these parameters to get a splash screen to display -->
        <param name="splashscreensource" value="ClientBin/splash_spinner.xaml" />
        <param name="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" value="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" />
        <!-- add these parameters to display to Silvelight installation/upgrade instructions -->
        <param name="onUpgradeRequired" value="onUpgradeRequired" />
        <param name="onInstallRequired" value="onInstallRequired" />
        <param name="onRestartRequired" value="onRestartRequired" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration: none">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
        <param name="initParams" runat="server" id="prmInitParams" value="dummy=" />
    </object>
    <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
        border: 0px"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="unsupported">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I figured this out last night.  Thanks.  You are correct as well.  A blank value for the InitParams parameter was to blame.  I've logged a bug with Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/637371/firefox-and-chrome-prompting-for-sl4-install-ie8-is-fine